# SharpZipLib not compressing memory stream

Tags: c#, zip

I have a memory stream that I want to compress:

```
public static MemoryStream ZipChunk(MemoryStream unZippedChunk) {

        MemoryStream zippedChunk = new MemoryStream();

        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(zippedChunk);
        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(3);

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("name");
        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

        Utils.StreamCopy(unZippedChunk, zippedChunk, new byte[4096]);
        zipOutputStream.CloseEntry();

        zipOutputStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
        zipOutputStream.Close();
        zippedChunk.Close();

        return zippedChunk;
    }

public static void StreamCopy(Stream source, Stream destination, byte[] buffer, bool bFlush = true) {
        bool flag = true;
        while (flag) {

            int num = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (num > 0) {                    
                destination.Write(buffer, 0, num);
            }

            else {

                if (bFlush) {                        
                    destination.Flush();
                }

                flag = false;
            }
        }           
    }
```

It's supposed to be quite simple. You provide it with a stream you want to compress. The methods compresses the stream and returns it. Great.

However, I don't get compressed stream back. What I get are streams that have about 20ish bytes added at the beginning and end, which seem to have something to do with the zip library. But the data in the middle is completely uncompressed (ranges of 256 bytes that have same value, etc). I tried upping the level to 9, but nothing changed.

Why aren't my streams compressing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You yourself copy original stream right into output stream via:

```
Utils.StreamCopy(unZippedChunk, zippedChunk, new byte[4096]);
```

You should copy to `zipOutputStream` instead:

```
StreamCopy(unZippedChunk, zipOutputStream, new byte[4096]);
```

Side note: instead of using custom copy stream methods - use a default one:

```
unZippedChunk.CopyTo(zipOutputStream);
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something dumb, I just couldn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Will fix it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in this case returned stream is disposed (via `zippedChunk.Close();`) so unrestored position is not the biggest problem :)